# In a tsconfig file, what is the difference between "types" and "lib"?

Tags: typescript

I've found questions about these tsconfig properties in isolation, but I haven't found a question comparing and contrasting the two.

As far as I can gather from the documentation, [lib](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) and [types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types) do the same thing: add types to the global scope. There are some differences in how the values are used.

##### lib

An array of keywords (e.g., "es5"). Each keyword is associated with one to many types.

##### types

An array of strings. Each string refers to a `package.json` dependency (or devDependency) that has `@types/` as a prefix.

---

Is this the only difference?

Comment: I didn't want to confuse things by putting two questions in one post, but I'm assuming any "lib" could be replaced with one to many "types" values. Is that true?

Comment: I've always considered (at a VERY high level) lib as focusing on specifying the available built-in language features and APIs, whereas types focus on importing type declarations for external packages and modules.

Comment: @DanielG "*for*" external packages and modules? Did you mean "*from*"? Otherwise, I think I'll need an example to understand.

Answer (score 0):

`lib` is a list of *builtins* like `lib.es5.d.ts`. They describe the environment itself. (e.g. 'es2020' won't have features added into browsers since then)

`types` is a list of *packages* like `express` and *files* like `./my-global-types.ts`

Comment: Can you define "builtins" and "packages"? Aside from using the wrong terms, was my explanation correct?